# A few declarations of variables

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to make a **server** using a socket library. But when I try to compile my project, it returns these errors:

```
/home/sulik/projects/Server/obj/x64/Debug/Socket.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Server::IP_Address[abi:cxx11]';
/home/sulik/projects/Server/obj/x64/Debug/main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
    Server

/home/sulik/projects/Server/obj/x64/Debug/Socket.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `Server::PortOfCon';
/home/sulik/projects/Server/obj/x64/Debug/main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

**I use WSL 2.0, if this information are useful.**

I haven't any idea why this error happens.

**This is my code:**

main.cpp

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include "Socket.h"
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {
    int sock = socket(INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in addr;

    if (Server::Connect(sock, (sockaddr&)addr) < 0) {
        perror("Connect() error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Socket.h

```
#include <string>
#define INET AF_INET

class sockaddr;

namespace Server {
    int PortOfCon = 8000;
    std::string IP_Address = "127.0.0.1";

    int Connect(int &sock, sockaddr& ADDR);
}
```

Socket.cpp

```
#include "Socket.h"
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int Server::Connect(int &sock, sockaddr &ADDR) {
    int ListeningSocket = socket(INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PortOfCon);
    addr.sin_family = INET;
    inet_aton(IP_Address.c_str(), &addr.sin_addr);

    if (bind(ListeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
        return -1;

    if (listen(ListeningSocket, 10) < 0)
        return -1;

    socklen_t sizeOfAddr = sizeof(ADDR);

    sock = accept(ListeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&ADDR, &sizeOfAddr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't declare global variables in a header like this.  If you absolutely _must_ use globals, then declare it extern, then define it in _one_ of your source files.

Comment: Or, instead of `extern`, you can simply declare the variables as `const` in the namspace, or as `inline static constexpr`, then you don't have to separate their declaration from their definition.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare global variables in a header like this. If you absolutely must use globals, then declare it extern, then define it in one of your source files.

Or, instead of extern, you can simply declare the variables as const in the namspace, or as inline static constexpr, then you don't have to separate their declaration from their definition.

**The second answer helped me**